# Weblogic RegistryDocumentBuilderFactory JXDocumentBuilderFactory

Tags: exception, weblogic

> java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilderFactory cannot be cast to oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory

weblogic is still using its own class,i have tried every method,modify the weblogic.xml and weblogic-application.xml  and add args to the startWebLogic.cmd `-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl`

all above is not to work!!!
who knows the method,please help me !

Comment: Please don't use words like "URGENT" and "IMMEDIATE" in your question titles. While your question may be urgent to you, others have what they consider equally important (and urgent) questions. This is a free peer-support site, and no one's question is more important or urgent than another. If you instead spend time asking your question better, you improve your chances of getting a rapid response. Phrasing your question title better by using pertinent information instead of wasting the space with URGENT also provides more info that might attract the attention of someone who can help as well. :)

Comment: ok，thanks，I would do it next time

Answer (score 0):

yeah，I have solved it.
find startWebLogic.cmd  in the directory bin
find the "set CLASSPATH"
modify it to be this:
                     set PRE_CLASSPATH=%WL_HOME%\server\lib\xerces.jar
                     set CLASSPATH=%PRE_CLASSPATH%;%SAVE_CLASSPATH%
just this,let your jar is

Comment: but notice that,xercesImpl.jar,this jar package contains methods which weblogic will load by itself,so it must put before xerces.jar,like this set PRE_CLASSPATH=%WL_HOME%\server\lib\xercesImpl.jar;%WL_HOME%\server\lib\xerces.jar

Answer (score 0):

Try removing xml-apis.jar from the classpath.

Sol to similar problem : http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?22597-java-lang-ClassCastException-weblogic-xml-jaxp-RegistryDocumentBuilderFactory